# How to show multiple checkbox in one label

Tags: vb.net

Anyone know how to showing multiple checkbox in vb.net  that checked in one label, like hoby checkbox. If i check 3 hoby, i want that 3 hoby show like cooking, football, watching.  Help me please. I need to learn more about vb
But if i just choose 2 hobbies, the label will just show 2 hobbies

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour].  This is not a tutorial site - you need to make some effort and do research

Comment: Sorry for bad english. I just need a help

Comment: We can't help until you can clearly explain what you're asking.

Comment: I have 8 checkbox. I want each checkbox that i have checked, shown on label. I want the text of each checkbox that checked shown on label.

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through your CheckBoxes on your form and if they are checked, add them to a list.  Then join your list together into a single string:

```
Dim checkedItems As New List(Of String)
For Each cb As CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
  If cb.Checked Then
    checkedItems.Add(cb.Text)
  End If
Next
YourLabel.Text = String.Join(", ", checkedItems.ToArray)
```

If the CheckBoxes are inside a panel, replace the "Me" with the panel name.

You can do the above in one line, too:

```
YourLabel.Text = String.Join(", ", Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox) _
                                              .Where(Function(x) x.Checked) _
                                              .Select(Function(x) x.Text))
```